# How to inject presenter into Fragment with Dagger2?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvp

I have RegisterPresenterImpl that I want to inject into fragment. My app crash when I am calling method register() of that presenter.It says that my presenter is null.

How I can solve this?

```
public class RegisterAccountFragment extends Fragment implements RegisterAccountView {


@Inject
RegisterAccountPresenterImpl registerPresenter;

public RegisterAccountFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_account, container, false);

 DaggerRegisterAccountComponent.builder()
            .netComponent(((App) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent())
            .registerAccountModule(new RegisterAccountModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this);

   registerPresenter.register(getName(), getEmail(), getPassword(), getConfirm());
     } 
}
```

**Component interface:**

```
 @FragmentScoped
 @Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules =  RegisterAccountModule.class)
  public interface RegisterAccountComponent {
       void inject(RegisterAccountFragment fragment);
}
```

Here is **module** class:

```
@Module
public class RegisterAccountModule {

private RegisterAccountView view;

public RegisterAccountModule(RegisterAccountView view){
    this.view = view;
}


@Provides
@FragmentScoped
RegisterAccountView providesRegisterAccountView(){
    return view;
   }
}
```

Here is class called RegisterPresenterImpl

```
 public class RegisterAccountPresenterImpl implements RegisterAccountPresenter{

private RegisterAccountView view;
private Retrofit retrofit;
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@Inject
public RegisterAccountPresenterImpl(Retrofit retrofit, RegisterAccountView view){
    this.retrofit = retrofit;
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public void register(String name, String email, String password, String confirm) {
    // CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your `ApplicationComponent` called `NetComponent`?

Answer (score 3):

Provide your `RegisterAccountPresenterImpl` in `RegisterAccountComponent`

It should be like this:

```
@FragmentScoped
@Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules =  
RegisterAccountModule.class)
public interface RegisterAccountComponent {
   void inject(RegisterAccountFragment fragment);

   RegisterAccountPresenterImpl getRegisterAccountPresenterImlp();
}
```

There is something about your implementation

1. `Inject Constructor/Field/Method` is not support `public` yet. Remove that redundant keyword
2. Init your `DaggerRegisterAccountComponent` in `onCreate()` instead of `onCreateView()` to make sure it will be built before using any dependency.
3. Consider using `final` for all `field` in `RegisterAccountPresenterImpl` which is set inside constructor. Because it will initialize one time only.

> ```
> private final RegisterAccountView view;
>
> private final Retrofit retrofit;
> ```

4. I just don't understand why you have to define a `view` (which is your fragment) inside a `presenter` and vice versa. Is this a circular dependency?

I found this [tutorial](https://blog.mindorks.com/essential-guide-for-designing-your-android-app-architecture-mvp-part-2-b2ac6f3f9637) is the super cool post about using MVP and Dagger. Please consider to read it

One more thing: If you want to debug Dagger-2 effectively, go to your `Dagger...Component` class to see what was built in there. Android Studio will help you find any issues when using it.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
public class RegisterAccountFragment extends Fragment implements RegisterAccountView {       
    @Inject
    RegisterAccountPresenter registerPresenter; // <-- not impl, why use DI then?
```

And

```
@FragmentScoped // <-- scope here
public class RegisterAccountPresenterImpl implements RegisterAccountPresenter{

    private final RegisterAccountView view;
    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    public RegisterAccountPresenterImpl(Retrofit retrofit, RegisterAccountView view){
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Module
public class RegisterAccountModule {

    private RegisterAccountView view;

    public RegisterAccountModule(RegisterAccountView view){
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Provides
    // @FragmentScoped // <-- no need for scoping item in module
    RegisterAccountView providesRegisterAccountView(){
        return view;
    }

    @Provides // <-- provide constructor injected stuff and bind to interface
    RegisterAccountPresenter registerAccountPresenter(RegisterAccountPresenterImpl impl) {
        return impl;
    }
}
```